# Install ruby 2.0 under Ubuntu 15.04 box

Tags: package-management, updates, 15.04, ppa, ruby

I have a problem when trying to install ruby 2.0 under Ubuntu 15.04 box
I have add `ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng` with bellow command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
```

And I get following error when I use `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA [Brightbox Ruby NG](https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng) has no packages for Vivid. But Ruby 2.0 is in the [Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&searchon=names&keywords=ruby) for your Ubuntu Vivid installation.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ruby
```

Comment: If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑**  now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to askubuntu.com/questions/ask